# SharePoint Alerts : It's possible to provide information about what has been changed in the notification that is sent to the users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

Today the notifications tells the user that something has been changed on this particular page but it doesn't tell the user what has been changed. it's possible to provide information about what has been changed in the notification that is sent to the users.
Is there any way to achieve it by out of the box functionality or we need to do it by customization.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB function to achieve the goal ,all the SharePoint alert notification is by default and we cannot edit it , but you can customize the default alert template .

http://blog.zebsadiq.com/post/SharePoint-2010-custom-alert-template.aspx 
http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-cusomize-alert-email-for.html